# How can I include an user preprocessor in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c-preprocessor, eclipse-cdt, preprocessor

I would like to include in my Eclipse CDT project the following prepocessor directive: `-D__SHRT_BIT=16` which I have seen that is used in the compiler call, but it is missing in Eclipse,as shown below.
[image]

I have tried to use the option C/C++ General >> Preprocessor Include Path >>CDT User Settings Entries to set it (as shown below).
[image]

However, it seems not to be working. Does anyone know why this approach is not valid or what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue, it was something simple, I was defining the value wrongly for the Macro. I was inserting an extra equal following those in the .h file, whereas I should I have set only one

For example

- Wrong => Name:`__SHORT_BIT` , Value:`=16` => Produces: `__SHORT_BIT==16`
- Right => Name:`__SHORT_BIT` , Value:`16`  => Produces: `__SHORT_BIT=16`